# Loopback: POST an array of objects through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm struggling with a Loopback issue using ajax. I try to POST an array of objects through jQuery function `.ajax()` but I just simply can't. The server always send me a 422 error (Unprocessable Entity).

The curious thing is: I am able to do the exact same request using the GUI explorer or the command line.

I have two models: Nemo & PendingUpdates associated through a hadMany/belongsTo relation (I've truncated them to be more readable):

```
// nemo.json
{
  "name": "Nemo",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": true,
      "required": false,
      "generated": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "pendingUpdates": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "PendingUpdate",
      "foreignKey": "nId"
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
// pending-update.json
{
  "name": "PendingUpdate",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "Number",
      "id": true,
      "required": false,
      "generated": true
    },
    "nId": {
      "type": "Number",
      "required": true
    },
    "parameter": {
      "type": "String",
      "required": false
    },
    "requestType": {
      "type": "Number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "nemo": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Nemo",
      "foreignKey": "nId"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the thing: I try to POST an array of pendingUpdates. Using the strongloop explorer, I just `POST` this: on `/Nemos/{id}/pendingUpdates` with id: 2 and data: `[{"requestType": 3, "parameter": "stuff"}, {"requestType": 2, "parameter": "otherStuff"}]`. I have a 200 response code with the created objects in the body.

However, when I try to send the exact same request client side using jQuery, I got a 422.

Here's the snippet:

```
var data = [
            {"requestType": 3, "parameter": "stuff"}, 
            {"requestType": 2, "parameter": "otherStuff"}
        ];
$.ajax("/api/Nemos/2/pendingUpdates?access_token=xxxxxxxxx", {
        data: data,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        method: "POST"
    }).done(success)
    .fail(fail);
```

I've tried using directly `data`, with `{data}`, `{"data": data}`, `JSON.stringify({"data": data})`, `JSON.stringify(data)`...

Could someone help me?

Thank you very much,

Bjorge

Comment: It seems that jQuery has a curious behaviour with arrays in its `.ajax()` function:

> *data:* It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See `processData` option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. **If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key** based on the value of the `traditional` setting (described below). <

Somebody knows how to prevent this? I tried to use the `traditional` attribute both with `true` and `false` attributes and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a day trying things with the console and WireShark, I've found what was wrong ; I'll write down the answer here to help future people with the same issue.

- First, as I assumed in my comment, the trouble didn't come from LoopBack which would misinterpret the data sent to it, but from jQuery: the `POST` request was sent, but without any data.
- Then, I managed to send a proper `POST` request (ie. with a JSON object, not an array). I was able to see that there was two `Content-Type` headers. I changed my function in order to send only one.
- Finally, I was able to make the request run correctly with the following code:

.

```
var data = [
            {"requestType": 3, "parameter": "stuff"}, 
            {"requestType": 2, "parameter": "otherStuff"}
        ];
$.ajax("/api/Nemos/2/pendingUpdates?access_token=xxxxxxxxx"), {
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        accept: "application/json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        method: "POST"
    }).done(success)
    .fail(fail);
```

I hope it will help somebody in the future.